# I want to create a image slider that automaticly slides all similar images in a folder

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, image, slider

Let's say I have a bunch of images with date based file names like these:

url/images/top20110326.png

url/images/top20110327.png

url/images/top20110328.png

url/images/top20110329.png

url/images/top20110330.png

url/images/top20110331.png

url/images/top20110401.png

url/images/top20110402.png

I would like to find some type of code or tool or plugin that would give me these functions:

1. automatically loads the images given all the url addresses of the images.
2. give the user a slider to quickly slide through the images in the order of the dates
3. give the user an option to automatically slide the images (without any effect, simply replace one with the other). Preferably with adjustable speeds.
4. the box that display the image's size should be adjustable in the code, and the image should resize or stretch to fit the box if needed.

PS: the server is a PHP server

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: I don't have anything yet except these images. I'm trying to find a already developed solution that would just allow me to modify it, and not have to build from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you need is this:
1. read the files of your image gallery folder via Java, PHP or another Server-Side languages.
2. make a list of their names (and if you like other information).
3. show them via javascript OR jQuery...

you can read the folder files by using this code in PHP:

```
$dir = getcwd()."/ImageGalleryFolder/";

if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..' ) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) {

                                // YOU HAVE FILENAME HERE ($file), USE IT AS YOU LIKE!
                                // note: the complete path of your file is $dir.$file
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

There are many free javascript and jQuery Image Sliders & Carousels in the net... Some of them even can read a folder of images (but I don't remember their names)...

Take a look at these places (and you can find more by googling)...

http://www.blogohblog.com/20-killer-image-sliders-carousels/

http://www.vivalogo.com/vl-resources/javascript-slideshows-sliders-carousels.htm

Comment: You can use `glob("url/images/top*.png");`